# How process() method in kafka-stream-processor is called automatically?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am learning kafka streams and have written a simple app, snippet below:

**MainApp:**

```
        Topology topology = new Topology();

        topology.addSource("SOURCE", "source-topic");
        topology.addProcessor("Processor1", () -> new Processor1(), "SOURCE");
        topology.addProcessor("Processor2", () -> new Processor2(), "Processor1");
        topology.addProcessor("Processor3", () -> new Processor3(), "Processor2");
        topology.addSink("SINK", "sink-topic", "Processor3");

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, config);
        streams.start();
```

**Snippet of Individual stream proccesor:**

```
public class Processor1 implements Processor<String, String> {

   // Rest of code

    @Override
    public void process(String key, String value) {
        System.out.println("Inside Processor1#process() method");
        context.forward(key, value);
    }
```

I understood that we need to create `Topology` and then to initiate it, we invoke `streams.start();`

I am not able to understand how `process()` method is being invoked automatically and who calls it?

Answer (score 1):

`Processor process()` method invoked by `ProcessorContextImpl` class automatically on each incoming message for specific topology node.
For your built topology, when a message arrived at the incoming topic, `SOURCE` node consumes it and forwards (propagates) message to child node by internally calling `forward` method (you could debug/take a look at code from class `ProcessorContextImpl`). In your case, `SOURCE` node forwards key and value to child node `Processor1`. After that, `process()` method from class `Processor1` triggered. When code reaches `context.forward()`, message forwards to the next child node, `Processor2`. After that message propagates to `Processor3` and `SINK` nodes in a similar manner, and finally, message produced to outbound topic. Such pipeline for specific message executes on a single thread (and if you have a default value for config `num.stream.threads = 1`, all messages will be processed on a single thread per app instance).